# pagination using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a little problem with pagination class of codeigniter
Here is my controller

```
function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/books/index/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('books');
        $config['per_page'] = '5';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        echo "Here";
        //load the model and get results
        $this->load->model('books_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->books_model->get_books($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

        // load the HTML Table Class
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->table->set_heading('Title');

        // load the view
        $this->load->view('books_view', $data);
    }
```

and here is the view

```
<body>
<h1>Books</h1>
<?php echo $this->table->generate($results); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</body>
```

and the model

```
function get_books($num, $offset) {
    $query = $this->db->get('books', $num, $offset);    
    return $query;
  }
```

I setup my database, and routes (default->books) already but the page doesn't show anything. My database table is books.

Comment: are you sure you are getting results from the database.  If you get no results the pagination won't show

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `$config` is a variable of your own class. If it is the global config, maybe your should set its parameters using `$this->config->set_item` function.

Furthermore, to avoid troubles like @Henesnarfel mentioned before, try to echo the number of results when you execute the query.

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->config->set_item('base_url',base_url().'index.php/books/index/');
    $this->config->set_item('total_rows',$this->db->count_all('books'));

    // ECHO to make me sure that the query is succesfully done
    echo("Found ".$this->db->count_all('books')." books");

    $this->config->set_item('per_page','5');
    $this->config->set_item('full_tag_open','<p>');
    $this->config->set_item('full_tag_close','</p>');
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    echo "Here";

    //load the model and get results
    $this->load->model('books_model');
    $data['results'] = $this->books_model->get_books($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    // load the HTML Table Class
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->table->set_heading('Title');

    // load the view
    $this->load->view('books_view', $data);
}
```